# Scala: try different day formats

Tags: scala

What is scala, elegant, functional way to parse a string using different date formats?

Let's say I have

```
val formats = Set(
  new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd"),
  new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/YYYY")
)
```

and I want to try parse a string using the first of those formats, which will parse successfully:

```
def parse(s:String): Option[Date] = {
  formats.map {??????????????}
}
```

Comment: You can create regexes for the different formats, and then match on them. See here: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/util/matching/Regex.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the list into a Stream (to make sure only the minimum number of parsing attempts are done), then use `Try` and `collectFirst`:

```
def parse(s:String): Option[Date] = {
  formats.toStream.map(f => Try(f.parse(s))).collectFirst {
    case Success(d) => d
  }
}

println(parse("2017-02-01"))  // Some(Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2017)
println(parse("02/01/2017"))  // Some(Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2017)
println(parse("23:00"))  // None
```

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't `.view` be a better alternative to creating a stream?

Comment: Oh - most definitely!